# I get the following error "E/Sync: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0)"

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I get the following error
 "E/Sync: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0)"
I have gone through many solutions in stack overflow. But unable to get the appropriate solution

```
Following is the code:
  public void execute() {
    if (mTableName.contentEquals("removed")) {
        String query = "Select * from removed";
        Cursor cursor = LODatabaseUtility.getInstance().cursorFromQuery(
                query);
        List<String> tableName = LODatabaseUtility.getInstance()
                .dataListfromCursor(cursor, "table_name");
        cursor = LODatabaseUtility.getInstance().cursorFromQuery(query);
        List<String> number = LODatabaseUtility.getInstance()
                .dataListfromCursor(cursor, "number");
        cursor = LODatabaseUtility.getInstance().cursorFromQuery(query);
        List<String> removedTimestamp = LODatabaseUtility.getInstance()
                .dataListfromCursor(cursor, "timestamp");
        if (number.size() == 0 || tableName.size() == 0) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tableName.size(); ++i) {
            query = "Select timestamp from " + tableName.get(i) + " where "
                    + tableName.get(i) + "_id = " + number.get(i);
            cursor = LODatabaseUtility.getInstance().cursorFromQuery(query);
            String tableTimestamp = LODatabaseUtility.getInstance()
                    .dataStringfromCursor(cursor);
            try {

                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                Date removedDate, tableDate;
                removedDate = df.parse(removedTimestamp.get(i));
                tableDate = df.parse(tableTimestamp);

                if (removedDate.compareTo(tableDate) > 0) {
                    query = "Delete from " + tableName.get(i) + " where "
                            + tableName.get(i) + "_id = " + number.get(i);
                    LODatabaseUtility.getInstance().getDatabase()
                            .execSQL(query);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Sync", "" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    getSyncTimeFromServer(mTableName);
}

I get the error pointing to the following line of code:
tableDate = df.parse(tableTimestamp);
```

Only for a particular table the timestamp value is giving the error. For the rest of the tables that I have the timestamp value, the value is inserted properly. Any help would be useful

Comment: removedTimestamp is empty, there is nothing to get().

Comment: The following line of code is used to set value to removedTimestamp:          List<String> removedTimestamp = LODatabaseUtility.getInstance()
                .dataListfromCursor(cursor, "timestamp");